# Is there a way to copy the file contents from a different containers to host file system?

Tags: python, shell, docker, docker-container, docker-image

I'm trying to copy the text file from a docker container to a host file system. We can do this using the docker cp command but the real issue is : There is a possibility that there might be a different container of the same image because my virtual machine will restart after sometime. And there will be a different container id for the same image when I restart my machine.
I have to include this commands in the python script and so I can not change the container ID explicitly.

I have tried the **docker cp** command in which we have to mention the container id.

```
def function():
    write some data into the file.
    file.close()
    """
    I need to execute commands or bash script here so that file I have 
    created in the container can be copied to host file system given 
    container id will change because of the machine restart. 
    """
```

Comment: Is the container always going to have the same name? Is it going to be the only one running? Is it going to be the only one running using a known image? You need something unique to key into.

Comment: How do you ordinarily find the container ID?  Can you reproduce that logic in code?

Comment: IME it is usually easier to start a container with a `docker run -v` option to establish a shared directory with the host than to manually `docker cp` files.  If local file I/O is the only thing your application does, it will also be significantly easier to run outside of Docker (and it will work correctly with little details like filesystem permissions).

Comment: How the container start after your vm restart?